# Source ~/.zshrc needed after OSX terminal restart

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, autocomplete

I have some zsh custom autocomplete set up in OSX for a custom command I have. These autocomplete functions are defined in `~/.zshrc`. If I restart the OSX Terminal, I see that the autocomplete does not work as expected. I need to type `source ~/.zshrc` for it to work again. Any idea why this is? How can I avoid having to call `source ~/.zshrc`?

Comment: Found the answer in http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71253/what-should-shouldnt-go-in-zshenv-zshrc-zlogin-zprofile-zlogout

Comment: (i) Check if your `.zshrc` gets source'd at all (e.g. put in an `echo all right` line) (ii) Make sure that your ,,autocomplete functions'' do not depend on definitions which follow only afterwards in your `.zshrc`. (iii) Without some more detailed information it's hard to tell what's going on.